# Expo-three save image from canvas

Tags: image, three.js, expo

How do I save a resulting image made by `expo-three` in buffer or into storage?
Is any way to do it not by making a shot of phone's screen?
Somehow chrome and other browser can make a screenshot just for canvas. Do they build an image data from scratch? And if it's then how?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I researched some info I found out that library `react-native-view-shot` ([more](https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/screenshot/)) is good for me. I can take a screenshot on any view I sent as `ref` to it.